# JavaFX Maven jfx:jar error: Could not find artifact javafx-packager

Tags: java, maven, javafx, compiler-errors

**I am trying to build an executable file using JavaFX and Maven.**

'clean javafx:run' is working fine but when I run 'mvn clean jfx:jar' (in eclipse or cmd) I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar (default-cli) on project inkoop: Execution default-cli of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar failed: Plugin com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]
```

.
**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>nl.myname.programs</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>nl.myname.programs.name.App</mainClass>
                <executable>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.2/bin/java</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <jfxMainAppJarName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
                <mainClass>nl.myname.programs.name.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>
</build>
```

My path has both `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin` (%JAVA_HOME is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2`)

Is there any way I can build my application?
Do I need both `javax-maven-plugin`'s?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you ever get to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I used org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin with the jlink goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the `com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin` does not work with Java 11+ / JavaFX 11+.

Just use the [`org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) with Java 11+ / JavaFX 11+.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried using org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin but I cant seem to find a way to build a jar or exe file? Is this possible with this plugin? Thanks again!

Comment: @Banjer_HD I haven't used it much yet, but the Java 11+ way seems to be to use jlink. The plugin has a jlink goal.

Comment: It is working with jlink now, thanks! But I still have one problem: I can't use the SQLite JDBC driver because it is an old jar file (non-modular). It doesn't work as automodule. Is there a way to fix this you know of? @Puce